# App Internal Testing Review Shows "Draft" - How to Proceed?

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

I'm currently in the process of developing an Android/iOS application, and I've reached the stage where I want to conduct internal testing before releasing it to the public. I've uploaded my app to the respective app stores' internal testing platforms (Google Play for Android), but I've encountered an issue.

When I check the status of my app on the internal testing platform, it's displaying "Draft" instead of being available for testing. I've followed the guidelines provided by both Google and Apple for internal testing setup, including creating testing groups and assigning testers. However, I can't seem to figure out why my app remains in "Draft" status.

Here are a few things I've already tried:

Double-checked my app's configurations and settings in the developer console.
Ensured that the build is uploaded and selected for testing.
Verified that my testers have accepted the invitations.
Despite these efforts, I can't seem to get past the "Draft" status, and my testers are unable to access the app for testing.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with internal testing on the Google Play platform? If so, could you please provide some guidance on how to resolve this issue and make my app available for testing?

I'd appreciate any insights or tips on how to get past this hurdle. Thanks in advance for your help!

[this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pNn8.png)

[this is how error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrYAo.png)

[this is how warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmEk7.png)

[this is one more error popup always display on my play console I update my android version to Android 13 (API level 33) and trying to publish app for internal testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxuam.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you are using a firebase dependency and as such, need to update your declaration.

- Click `update declaration`
- Does your app use advertising id? Select `yes`.
- Why does your app need to use advertising id? Select the `analytics` checkbox then save.

Try submit your app again. You should not have that error.

Comment: should i also need to resolve that warning messages. please check my one more image that i just posted in my question

Comment: Its a warning. You don't need to resolve. It is asking for an obfuscation trace file.

flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=.

That above command would generate the the app bundle and also generate debug symbols in the project root which you can upload to play console.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your app contains ads, or some package, that uses Advertisement ID permission.
You need to find this in App Content tab and complete declaration

Comment: i declare it already and then upload. still getting same error

Comment: You need to select under Advertisement ID Yes, And complete how You are using it.